# .net 7 MAUI iOS Release build from azure devops works on iOS 15 devices but not iOS 16 devices

Tags: .net, msbuild, maui

I'm using Azure DevOps to create an ad-hoc build for iOS for a .net 7 MAUI application (recently updated from .net 6 which had the same issue):

```
dotnet publish -f net7.0-ios -c Release -r ios-arm64 /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true
```

The .ipa file produced by the build works on iOS 15 devices but when I download it on an iOS 16 device the icon is blank and when I tap it to open it says the application cannot be installed at this time.  Has anyone successfully published a MAUI release build for iOS 16?

Comment: This could be a potential issue, I see you have posted [MAUI 7.0 iOS Release build won't install on iOS 16](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11385) in Github, you can continue following on that thread.